# how can I put a :after pseudo element as the container for sibling elements?

Tags: css

I have this `HTML` code that I should NOT edit.

I need a solution from css to have something like in this image,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEWVW.jpg

where a black rectangle is added, which contains the texts of: "Colombia" and "South america". I know that the solution is done using `pseudo-elements` like `:after`, but I'm new to this `CSS` topic and I don't know how to do it.

I appreciate your help, and I will be happy to learn.

```css
img{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
}

li{
 list-style:none;
}

li:after{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background:black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="offers">
  <li>
      <img  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Flag_of_Colombia.svg" alt="">
      <h3 class="country">colombia</h3>
      <div class="continent_ubication">south <span class="text_continent" >america</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the `list-style: none` declaration you have on the list element `<li>` doesn't have any effect. It should added to the unordered list `<ul>` style block.

As the picture doesn't include the red color, I assume you wanted to keep that. Here is a solution using pseudo elements. Specifically, using the `::after` element and positioning the black box right underneath the flag `<img>`. Then positioning the "colombia" and "south america" text using `position: relative` to move them into the alignment you wanted in the image.

Since your using a heading element `<h3>` for the "colombia" text it will have a larger `font-size` and `font-weight` than the `<div>` with text "south america". You could give them both similar font sizes and font weights to make them look "alike" unless you were going for a mismatched size appearance.

```css
img{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* Make <h3> and child <div> have same font-size and weight (remove this if you want them to be different size) */
ul li h3,
ul li div {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

ul li .country {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  top: -5rem;
  left: 4.5rem;
}

ul li .continent_ubication {
  position: relative;
  color: #2E86C1;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 7.5rem;
  bottom: 4.5rem;
}

li:after{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 15rem;
 width: 300px;
 height: 110px;
 z-index: 5;
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="offers">
  <li>
      <img  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Flag_of_Colombia.svg" alt="Flag of Colombia">
      <h3 class="country">colombia</h3>
      <div class="continent_ubication">south <span class="text_continent" >america</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello, it is an honor for me that you help me. Notice that I want a result like in the image that I put, I want the black layer to be above the flag, that is, above the red color as well. I have tried to do it with your code but with no result. I hope you can help me crack...

Comment: Hello. Yeah, you would just need to move the black pseudo element up a bit to cover the red layer of the flag, and adjust the relative positions of the the text. Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

That was quite a challenge to accomplish this without changing the html, but I think I did it (at least in codepen it works). I wasn't able to make it work with `li::after`, but I added the black background to the "South America" text and that worked fine. Here is the CSS:

```
img{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 180px;
  left: 60px;
}
li{
 list-style:none;
 position: relative;
}

.continent_ubication,
.text-continent {
  color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
  width: 160px;
  height: 60px;
  padding-left: 140px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  top: 170px;
}
```